# Can't excute a function when i click on li element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an **HTML list** like this:

```
<ul id='years'>
<li class='year'>2014</li>
<li class='year'>2015</li>
<li class='year'>2015</li>
</ul>
```

when I click on "2014" for example, I need to hide other list and show only the clicked one then pass this year to php file, catch this year and connect to a database baking with other data related to this year then list this new data at the end of list, and I tried this:

**jQuery part:**

```
<script> 
$('.year').click(function(){
var path=$(this).text();
$(".year").toggle(200);
$(this).toggle(200);
$.post("test.php",{p:path},function(data){
$(".years").append(data);
});

// last part of script
$(".col_1").click(function(){
//whatever 
});

</script>
```

**test.php:**

```
if(isset($_POST['p']){
$year=$_POST['p'];
$db_connection=new mysqli(localhost,USER,PASS) ;
$query="select*from user.info where year=$year" ;
$db_connection->query($query);
$rows=$db_connection->num_rows;
for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++){`
$result->data_seek($rowP);
$result->fetch_assoc()["col_1"];
$returned_data.="<li class='col_1'>$result</li>";
}
echo "$returned_data";
}
```

All of this work well and the data show up in the web page but the last part of script doesn't work and nothing happen when i click on any element of this list. Is the reason because the `<li class='col_1'>` coded by php or what?.. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move `$(".col_1").click(function(){` inside `Success` function in ajax

```js
$('.year').click(function(){
  debugger;
  var path=$(this).text();
  $(".year").toggle(200);
  $(this).toggle(200);
  $.post("test.php",{p:path},function(data){
    $(".years").append(data);
    $(".col_1").click(function(){
    //alert();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='years'>
<li class='year'>2014</li>
<li class='year'>2015</li>
<li class='year'>2015</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's work, thank you for help, but why i should move it inside $.post function and not working outside it.

Comment: @mohamedmaher because you don't have the `<li>` elements yet, until your Ajax returns

Comment: Firstly do you have any requirement that like  on `Success` you have to bind this click event ? or please let me know the purpose of this `click` handler so i can properly explain why you need to put in `Success` callback

Comment: The `$returned_data` has many nested `ul` and `li` and i need this `click` to hide entire `li` of all `ul` then show only the `li` related to clicked one and on the second click reverse this operation.

Comment: Ohh Ohkkk than @Accountantم said is the right once `$returned_data` is loaded on `DOM` after those elements you can bind `click` on this or you have to use `On` to bind dynamically added element like `$("body").on("click",".col_1",function(){` this and it could be placed on `ready` function or anywhere else according to your need

Comment: `$('.year').click(function(){});` after this click handler you can write or in `ready` function and one more thing `on` function in added in jquery version `1.7` so check your jquery version as well

Comment: I have jquary version `1.11.3`